How to download a Vue component as a PDF in Nuxt 3 without vulnerable packages?
I have a large hard-coded grid (more than 300 grid items) with many styles in my RiskGrid.vue component, which is located on the risk.vue page. The RiskGrid.vue component also contains smaller components called RiskGridTable.vue. I have a small button on the risk.vue page that should trigger a function to download the RiskGrid.vue component (with all its styles) as a PDF file.
I've tried using html2pdf, vue-html2pdf, and jspdf packages, but they have known vulnerabilities and did not give me the desired results. Are there any better ways to download that component as a PDF, or did I not use those packages correctly? The PDF should contain a title, description, and the grid.
Here are some code snippets to give you an idea of my structure:
risk.vue:
<TabPanel value="0" class="tab-panel">
    <div ref="rizikSazetakRef">
        <RiskGrid v-if="vrstaIzracuna == 'Djelatnost'" :tip="'RZ'" class="rizik-sazetak" />
        <span v-else>
            <font-awesome-icon icon="info-circle" style="margin-right: 5px;" />
            Nije odabrana vrsta izračuna
        </span>
    </div>
</TabPanel>
<button class="action-icon" @click="downloadRizikSazetak">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="download" size="lg" />
</button>

<script setup>
const downloadRizikSazetak = () => {
    // code for pdf download
};
</script>

Code snippet from RiskGrid.vue:
<template>
    <div class="rizik-sazetak">
        <div v-if="showPopup" class="success-popup">
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="'circle-exclamation'" />
            <span>{{ message }}</span>
            <div class="progress-bar" />
        </div>
        <div class="sazetak">
            <div ref="rizikSazetakRef" class="grid-table">
                <!-- more code -->
                <div class="grid-item vertical lightgreen db-l">Wind changes</div>
                <div class="grid-item table-header">First-al</div>
                <div class="grid-item table-header">First-bl</div>
                <div class="grid-item table-header">First-cl</div>
                <div class="grid-item table-header">First-dl</div>
                <div class="grid-item table-item nb-b">
                    <RiskGridTable :pozicija="12" :data="structuredData['12']" class="sazetak-table" />
                </div>
                <!-- more code -->
            </div>
            <LegendaBoja v-if="structuredData" class="legenda" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* more code */
.vertical {
    /* writing-mode: vertical-lr; */
    writing-mode: sideways-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-align: center;
    text-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;

    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(57) {
    grid-row: 7;
    grid-column: 12;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(58) {
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-column-start: 13;
    grid-row-end: 8;
    grid-column-end: 20;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(59) {
    grid-column: 20;
    grid-row: 4 / 8;
}
/* more code */
</style>

RiskGridTable.vue:
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="data" class="grid">
            <div class="_grid-item first-div" :class="getColorClass(data[0].history)">
                <span class="first" :style="getFontSize(data[0].history)">
                    {{ data[0].history }}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="_grid-item db-s" :class="getColorClass(data[0].p0_4_5)" :style="getFontSize(data[0].p0_4_5)">
                {{ data[0].p0_4_5 }}
            </div>
            <div class="_grid-item" :class="getColorClass(data[0].p0_8_5)" :style="getFontSize(data[0].p0_8_5)">
                {{ data[0].p0_8_5 }}
            </div>
            <!-- more code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


All the code is unrelated and irrelevant to the security concerns here. Any package or software is susceptible to have some security issues. It all depends on your threat-model and what you do with the PDF itself. Having a specific scope with details is welcome. But TLDR is: PDF is hard and have a lot of things to consider, if you do have the capabilities to create your own and avoid all the security edge-cases, then go for it. Otherwise, stick to an already existing pdf package.
